# Mr. ASCII becoming uncanny with your own code

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, unicode

Let's make a little stupid program that simulates the meme "[Mr. incredible becoming uncanny](https://www.google.com/search?q=mr%20incredible%20uncanny&rlz=1C1ONGR_esES970ES970&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs2e34ka_1AhXa_7sIHaP3BNIQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=969&dpr=1)", but in this case, our little ASCII friend is going to react to our code length.

**Objective:**

Create a program that takes anything (preferably a program) as input and outputs this:

```
Pov: 
<face>   you score X on codegolf
```

Where `X` is the length of the input and the face depends on the value of X:

```
X < 20         = \(^-^)/
20 ≤ X < 50    = -(o_o)-
50 ≤ X < 100   = /(¬_¬)\
100 ≤ X < 250  = /(º-º)\
250 ≤ X < 500  = /(ª@ª)\
X ≥ 500        = /(x_x)\
```

**Example:**

I have made my own ungolfed version in C#: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZKxisJAEIZr8xRDql1kNSekOa84sFUQrrjCaFjWdW8h7sDOKsrhC4lPYJkXyyVwzYGxkHQnTDf//38z8CsSCr2uqh1ZZ@DjSEFvx5EqJBHMPRovt/Ad9SjIYBXs0a5hJq1jFHxtWCxBekO8kfQm6AgLPfj0NuipdZrFc9y/xnwc1Vu7YY10kSwHU@1M@II3GCW8Md5yZhlbiRUfAsARd0DNlRD3/0b0Y0AHCtfaYLH5BZ10QRpu4dJ2nGCYIxdd0l6SdtyQlZe8vPAs65I4Su8Sr6K8dkxM7/94fi/PjxPbgw/54bHYqJ5T9Wz7s@3/pu0/)

```
using System;
class Program {
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Pov:");

    if(args[0].Length < 20){
        Console.WriteLine("\\(^-^)/   you score "+args[0].Length+" on codegolf");

    }else if(args[0].Length < 50){
        Console.WriteLine("-(o_o)-   you score "+args[0].Length+" on codegolf");

    }else if(args[0].Length < 100){
        Console.WriteLine("/(¬_¬)\\   you score "+args[0].Length+" on codegolf");

    }else if(args[0].Length < 250){
        Console.WriteLine("/(º-º)\\   you score "+args[0].Length+" on codegolf");

    }else if(args[0].Length < 500){
        Console.WriteLine("/(ª@ª)\\   you score "+args[0].Length+" on codegolf");

    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("/(x_x)\\   you score "+args[0].Length+" on codegolf");

    }
}
}
```

If the program takes itself as input, it will output:

```
Pov:
/(x_x)\   you score 741 on codegolf
```

**Rules:**

- The output must have exactly three spaces betwen the face and the text.
- The shortest code in bytes wins.
- Input length should be counted in characters, not bytes.

Comment: If we are to assume the input is always our own code, then we can [just ignore the input, per consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12442). At this point, the task is just to output one of these literal strings, and implementing the rest of the challenge becomes [unobservable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11228)

Comment: @pxeger yep, just after write this a had left my house for some time and i was thinking in that xd, i am going to fix this

Comment: Length of the input is what exactly?  Because usually string length is not the number of bytes.  In fact it seems most answers here don't even score themselves accurately.

Comment: @WheatWizard its true, i hadnt realized that some characters count as 2 bytes, but lets say that the count of bytes from the output is more ¿"symbolic"? or easier idk, i am going to add a rule about that to leave it clear

Comment: The new rule is still unclear. I've edited it to make it obvious.

Comment: @ZeroCodeException Still not fully clear. Characters as in bytes in the used charset, as in Unicode code points, as in Unicode grapheme clusters, or as in "whatever of these the language can output with the shortest code"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>118</s> <s>113</s> <s>112</s> 80 bytes

*-32 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
’ƒËŠˆ’Ig•È¼Ÿò8Ãx°иšü•"(\^-)/-o_¬ºª@x"Åв6ä•Û³™•51вT*ÅΔIg›}èJ.º“Pov:
ÿ  €îŒÂ ÿ€‰ ÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMY5MOdx9dcLoNyPRMf9Sw6HDHoT1HdxzeZHG4ueLQhgs7ji48vAcorKQRE6erqa@bH39ozaFdh1Y5VCgdbr2wyezwEpCe2Yc2P2pZBGSZGl7YFKJ1uPXcFJBhu2oPr/DSO7TrUcOcgPwyK67D@xUUHjWtObzu6KTDTQqH9wPZjxo2ABn//yspKQ0WxwCdAgA) Beats all other answers.

Comment: Well, it used to beat all the other correct answers, but I think you'll find that's not true any more...

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/22rdxwn8). Not sure why you do `’IO.‚Ø :€Ÿ’.E`, just take the input as multi-line string and use `I` instead. I've also golfed the `U5FXNè®›iNˆ]5ˆ¯н` to `ÅΔIg›}`, and you can remove the `ÀÀ` by not starting the base-string with \. @Neil Now it's true again. ;)

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMY5MOdx9dcLoNyPRMf9Sw6HDHoT1HdxzeZHG4ueLQhgs7ji48vAcorKQRE6erqa@bH39ozaFdh1Y5VCgdbr2wyezwEpCe2Yc2P2pZBGSZGl7YFKJ1uPXcFJBhu2oPr/DSO7TrUcOcgPwyK67D@xUUHjWtObzu6KTDTQqH9wPZjxo2ABn//yspKQ0WxwCdAgA) by using the mirror builtin for halve the faces.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Bah, and I had just found an 82-byte Charcoal golf...

Comment: (Actually 86 bytes because I'd miscounted. Although I did golf a further byte off.)

Comment: @emanresuA Those are in the codepage; see [`0xaa` and `0xba`](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md).

Comment: @Makonede Oh, okay.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>106</s> <s>102</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> 85 bytes

```
ＰPov:ＤＰ✂⁺”|ecT#Ｆ>”xªº´¬o^_@--_-ΣＥＩ⪪”←⧴⟲º"Ｑ⪫+R” ‹Ｌθιφ⁶←‖Ｂ”↶±=⧴KＣX≕‹#”ＩＬθ”↶←∨^⁹⁰y↔]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVC9SgNBEO59imUtsoc5jAEtFEXUzgRCYiH4x3Hu6cGaPe8nGLDIWQTtLNRKEfw3WkQJwYSt7gHiO@wL7COccxeImWZmvvm@4ZsxDw3X5AaL42LAfNtx7apPcInX5rG2MLEWHDkE8tiswmyTkhILPIKnIfTtbZIGziJ8ErWifvTJd/eWdX1Px1oWVYIjUjQcsmp4IHaYDetnczmUn82hGciQ8rlEi7AG9AL1PFKg1QP/kBxDb2sJamXRnJb44DVK5gvU8qEpU4tR018JfJ@6FqsnRktD/wihOg@QZ3KXIjzCUw@j5doYn1eRyffpAWcW0ON4K6NEO/mCEk9QydszGfZl4@6UmhuTSrwsQT08tvN/7uBRiWcl3mWrBWPZvJSvHXn/HfWxEl@y9TFVBhjJRk@Jz8HPoPfblGE3oTVulHhIJd3oaxFU60o8bsqLa@BOAg47U8mQkijO33Zl2JNhuy6bVzuZnVivsT8) Link is to verbose version of code. Note that the deverbosifier miscalculates the length of characters in the ISO-8851 code page; non-ASCII characters should count 3 bytes instead of 1. Explanation:

```
ＰPov:Ｄ
```

Print `Pov:` without moving the cursor (so it gets overwritten below), and output that on its own line.

```
Ｐ✂⁺”|ecT#Ｆ>”xªº´¬o^_@--_-ΣＥＩ⪪”←⧴⟲º"Ｑ⪫+R” ‹Ｌθιφ⁶
```

Concatenate the compressed string `////-\((((((` with the incompressible string `xªº¬o^_@--_-` (Charcoal can only compress ASCII strings), slice that with a starting offset depending on how many of the numbers in the compressed string `500 250 100 50 20` are greater than the length of the input and a step of 6, and print without moving the cursor.

```
←‖Ｂ
```

Butterfly the canvas, leaving the cursor after the face.

```
”↶±=⧴KＣX≕‹#”
```

Print the compressed string    `you score` .

```
ＩＬθ
```

Print the length of the input as a string.

```
”↶←∨^⁹⁰y↔]
```

Print the compressed string  `on codegolf`.

Comment: This does not output `Pov:`

Comment: @Makonede An almost identical fix ;-)

Comment: If you're scoring with a codepage you can only use characters in said codepage, which `ªº¬` don't appear to be.

Comment: @emanresuA `¬` is in said code page. Charcoal also has a 3-byte encoding for characters with ordinals less than 16512, however as I mention the deverbosifier doesn't actually perform the encoding so I manually adjusted the byte count.

Comment: @emanresuA To clarify, the deverbosifier only automatically adjusts the byte count for characters with ordinals above 255.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 151 bytes

```
=LET(x,LEN(A1),"Pov:
"&IFS(x<20,"\(^-^)/",x<50,"-(o_o)-",x<100,"/(¬_¬)\",x<250,"/(º-º)\",x<500,"/(ª@ª)\",1,"/(x_x)\")&"   you score "&x&" on codegolf")
```

Input is in the cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is.

Everything I try that seems more clever than this simple approach ends up adding a few bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 158 bytes

```python
x=len(open(0).read())
print("Pov:\n"+r"////-\((((((xªº¬o^_@-__-xªº¬o^))))))\\\\-/"[sum(x<q*10for q in[2,5,10,25,50])::6],f"  you score {x} on codegolf")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7cdPCoJAHIbhfacYZjVTY47aWElBR2ivJuGfEmx@Omoo0YWiE7T0YiYugu7gs/h4v7ytriCtvm/2WSwJ5MNwulTxOSKUznKVyorgI9wdT@KFwvpA88io6V7dp3vDKThoQaD9Lh15A03HblnfSLMr5gZPQKECpdI1mWAGZ6ZggvvUcWyfJRihFmpUhqBi9GieCCQKIYovkCWY9r1hWithrzdbPtVU//UF)

-1 byte thanks to pxeger
-9 bytes thanks to Kateba

Comment: [167](https://tio.run/##7cZNCoJAFADgfad4zOq9GnO07I@CjtA@f4jSEmyeqcVEdKHoBC69mAmtukObjy@/VyfWo7Y1qyzWyHmHomER7w5I1MuLVFcoNnxb@FoMhI0mMuSDjc1r3by@q62m/u4dNe9uFnLEZIGPoRWSLYZlnqUV0ra8ntEsL31HJVzABVK9daUnHSVdT3oqoEAmAuDOVyj3XMTwME9gDXs@xEfOEkFt67ijsTeZzubqv/9@9wE "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Got it down to [158](https://tio.run/##7cdPCoJAHIbhfacYZjVTY47aWElBR2ivJuGfEmx@Omoo0YWiE7T0YiYugu7gs/h4v7ytriCtvm/2WSwJ5MNwulTxOSKUznKVyorgI9wdT@KFwvpA88io6V7dp3vDKThoQaD9Lh15A03HblnfSLMr5gZPQKECpdI1mWAGZ6ZggvvUcWyfJRihFmpUhqBi9GieCCQKIYovkCWY9r1hWithrzdbPtVU//UF)

Comment: @Kateba oh, that's a nice trick

Comment: Interestingly this gives "152" as it's own score not 158.

Comment: @WheatWizard unless I've read the challenge specs wrong I believe this is intended since the scoring mechanism for this challenge is bytes, but the length of X should be given in character length and not true byte count.

Comment: Do you need to read from "open(0)" or can you just use "input"?

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired `input` would only take one line. this is the best way of reading all input at once

Comment: I'll be back in math.se chat in $\lfloor 11 \rfloor! days.  Just wanted to check in, I hope all is well.  Looking forward to being back in chat!  I am in the Meta.se chatroom "whatever quid: meta.se" https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1626/whatever-quid-meta-se, until then...

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 139 bytes

```
s`.+
Pov:¶$.&$*_   you score $.& on codegolf
_{500,}
/(x_x)\
_{250,}
/(ª@ª)\
_{100,}
/(º-º)\
_{50,}
/(¬_¬)\
_{20,}
-(o_o)-
_+
\(^-^)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/OEFPmysgv8zq0DYVPTUVrXgFBYXK/FKF4uT8olQFoJBCfp5Ccn5Kanp@ThpXfLWpgYFOLZe@RkV8hWYMkG9kCuEfWuVwaBVYxBCq4tAu3UO7wCIwJWviD62BaAIJ6Grkx@dr6nLFa3PFaMTpxmnqDy7XAAA) Explanation:

```
s`.+
Pov:¶$.&$*_   you score $.& on codegolf
```

Get the length of the input and substitute it into the output string, plus also insert that many underscores for the face checking.

```
_{500,}
/(x_x)\
_{250,}
/(ª@ª)\
_{100,}
/(º-º)\
_{50,}
/(¬_¬)\
_{20,}
-(o_o)-
_+
\(^-^)/
```

Replace the underscores with the appropriate face.

Comment: This does not output `Pov:`

Comment: @Makonede Whoops, overlooked that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 138 bytes

```sh
f='\(^-^)/-(o_o)-/(¬_¬)\/(º-º)\/(ª@ª)\/(x_x)\'
<<<"Pov:
${f:$[i=$#1/50+($#1>19),i>9?5:i>3?3+i/5:i]*7:7}   you score $#1 on codegolf"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsIwEEDRfU4xaMGMNTRVSmloq0dwb7ULbTQQHFCUqngh8QQuc7EYXf23@PfzwWuO3Otq1PCN2GAiOLWEIuHu3bo3NgEf4T5/vBbu9UPf9tiMWFmWgyVdFYseWkUrU0XDNMlkzEPrtMCJqYt5pkw9m89ikwStx7nKnwBwowuct3TqILxAR9jSrtuT1QOPjGk6gQWeSphKyCSkMij78W@JoCF6cKuswqf/Ag)

Fancy ternaries, let's go through them:

```sh
i=$#1/50+($#1>19)         # div by 50, add one if at least 20
i>9?5:                    # if i > 9, then $#1 was at least 500
      i>3?3+i/5           # else if i > 3, then $# was between 100 and 500
               :i         # else i is correct
```

---

```sh
      ${f:$[ ... ]*7:7}           # string slice starting from $[ ]*7 of length 7
<<<"..${f:$[ ... ]*7:7}...$#1.."  # substitute in string. Embedded newlines are fine
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>192</s> 191 bytes

```rust
|x:&str|print!("Pov:
{}   you score {} on codegolf",match x.len(){0..=19=>r"\(^-^)/",0..=49=>"-(o_o)-",0..=99=>r"/(¬_¬)\",0..=249=>r"/(º-º)\",0..=499=>r"/(ª@ª)\",_=>r"/(x_x)\"},x.len())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZBBboMwEEX3nGLKAtkSkLTKInFKVPUEVRddRbEQ2C0q2MjYDRXhQlFOkCUXoyYE7tCNPf/5z4z8lal0byoGlU4JySQhr4a/szjdOlxAEWcCYWggZxp41J9q4lVanUqVCf2A3Df5Q5ymBYBfaaBKpGJgpRSQyJR9ypy7fhHr5AvqMGd2VLMMw@hxE@2Uu0eH4IAXrj@glUVugCSVOBjJ5mZaoO5Cuwvej/BpNdFr0F0nupq955fuPFA66prWVrX@fTnut87wkcJoyERpzwg@WELIs1nvCBHsiPDooPZlDsQWQwphLpNveykbDjVCZzla@uDNw@6tt5rakKYRtiSEK1lQo/kaeaM5NOKo4nJY6HA0N1nZ/veU/wA)

*-1 byte thanks to [Aiden4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97691/aiden4)*

Comment: You can save a few bytes with type hint when assigning the closure, and by outputting directly to stdout. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZFBboMwEEX3OcWUBbIlIGmVReKUqOoJqi66imIhYreoYEfGbqgIF4pygiy5WDqEwB26sWee/8zY38aV9upKAaXdMZZpxl6dfBfJbjWRCookU4RCDbmwIJlUxC@toRCugcfXY3WU2hSJfSDem/5hk7oBgF/toEy1EYCpVpDqnfjUufQCVKZfUEW5wKb1LIrix2W8Nt6GbMMtnXpBh@aIvJBormnYk@VNNCXtmbdnuunh03ygl7C9DHQ@ak8v7amjvM8rXmHWBPfh9LqadE8qnIVM7XGN4UOkjD27xZoxJQ6E9gqOJ6M1GHR@RLlOv3EzaBN3ymY5mQXgj83upbeYo19DCwwZk0YX3Fm5IH4vjpw6mGTfDbyVaWf7C0kydsCzvcmUzRVaXTdecFchb/7zN/wB "Rust – Try It Online")

Comment: @Aiden4 Thanks, I didn't even think about printing to stdout. But using a closure type hint outside the counted bytes feels to much like cheating for me :-)

Comment: FYI, it's standard practice for the rust users of the forum to use type hints when assigning the closures, so long as it coerces into a function pointer of the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 155 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,i=0)=>[.4,1,2,5,10,n=s.length][i]*50>n?`Pov:
${"/-\\"[q=2>>i]}(${(c="^o¬ºªx"[i])+"-__-@_"[i]+c})${"\\-/"[q]}   you score ${n} on codegolf`:f(s,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY4xboMwGEb3nMKyGOxiHIPKEsmkR6jUEShBrk2pkP8Eu1EqxIWqnqAjF6Mwdgnjp6f39H3U19qpvj37yMKbnmcjiWOtFFRmOX9kMUtYymLBrHS807bx72Xelg@pyOzx9AzXwy4Y8D4qCpxfZJJlbTmSYCBK4leYfqbf6fuGF4GGOKqq6KlaR6hGulhFEe0XqxwRQl/wiZyCXqNgsCMCi9Ryp4HOnA5mfRTGdFZgHXSad9AQQwz38OL71jaEUrr7D/EN816fde1JLO7i5D5OxUZ8o55u5Vc@/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET 6)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <sup><s>190</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>172</s></sup> 170 bytes

```cs
int l=args[0].Length;Console.Write($"Pov:\n{(l<20?"\\(^-^)/":l<50?"-(o_o)-":l<100?"/(¬_¬)\\":l<250?"/(º-º)\\":l<500?"/(ª@ª)\\":"/(x_x)\\")}   you score {l} on codegolf");
```

*Golf of example code in OP*

Passing the program text as the first command line argument outputs:

```cs
Pov:
/(º-º)\   you score 170 on codegolf
```

Works on `.Net 6` but not on TIO.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 89 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“µð1|ż‘Ḥ‘>@LS‘ị“\-/“(“^oḄṾȥx“-__-@_‘ŒḄ‘6¦U7¦0ịxɗ€6a"ƊZỌ¤
L⁶;“£ṭṛẇṣLe“¦ŒɱṣṀ^Tż»jṭÇ“Pov:¶”;
```

A full program accepting a (Python formatted) string argument that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDWw9vMKw5uudRw4yHO5YASTsHn2AQZ3c3UDZGVx9IagBxXP7DHS0Pd@47sbQCyNONj9d1iAcqOzoJKAykzQ4tCzU/tMwAqK3i5PRHTWvMEpWOdUU93N1zaAmXz6PGbdYguxY/3Ln24c7ZD3e1P9y52CcVJLTs6KSTG4G8hzsb4kKO7jm0Owuo5nA7UCogv8zq0LZHDXOt////r66uPkQcC3QpAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDWw9vMKw5uudRw4yHO5YASTsHn2AQZ3c3UDZGVx9IagBxXP7DHS0Pd@47sbQCyNONj9d1iAcqOzoJKAykzQ4tCzU/tMwAqK3i5PRHTWvMEpWOdUU93N1zaAmXz6PGbdYguxY/3Ln24c7ZD3e1P9y52CcVJLTs6KSTG4G8hzsb4kKO7jm0Owuo5nA7UCogv8zq0LZHDXOt/wP5TWsi//@PVrdX18pTSMsvUshTyMxT0DDQUTC01FEwAtImQNoUSFsCaUMDIMMIJGJkCpYCyxloxgIA).

#### How?

```
“...‘Ḥ‘>@LS‘ị“...‘ŒḄ‘6¦U7¦0ịxɗ€6a"ƊZỌ¤ - Helper: list of characters, X
“...‘                                  - list of numbers = [9,24,49,124,249]
     Ḥ                                 - double = [18,48,98,248,498]
      ‘                                - increment = [19,49,99,249,499]
       >@L                             - length of X greater than? (vectorises)
          S                            - sum
           ‘                           - increment -> our "face index"
                                     ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
             “...‘                     -   list of lists of numbers
                                           ...the ordinals of the characters:
                                              "\-/", "(", "^o¬ºªx", "-__-@_"
                  ŒḄ                   -   bounce
                                           ...this appends:
                                              "^o¬ºªx", "(", "\-/"
                    ‘6¦                -   increment the sixth - 2nd "(" -> ")"
                       U7¦             -   reverse seventh - 2nd "\-/" -> "/-\"
                                  Ɗ    -   last three links as monad:
                               6       -     literal six
                             ɗ€        -     for each - f(list, 6):
                          0ị           -       get the last one
                            x          -       repeat it six times
                                a"     -       zip with logical AND
                                               ...effectively extend the lists to
                                                  length six using the rightmost
                                                  ordinal.
                                   Z   -   transpose
                                    Ọ  -   convert the integers to characters
                                           ...a list of the faces
            ị                          - "face index" index into "faces"

L⁶;“...»jṭÇ“Pov:¶”; - Main Link: list of characters, X
L                   - length of X
 ⁶;                 - prefix with a space
   “...»            - compressed list of strings = "   you score", " on codegolf"
        j           - join with the score
          Ç         - call the helper link, above with X as the argument -> face
         ṭ          - tack the face to the front
           “Pov:¶”  - "Pov\n"
                  ; - concatenate
                    - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 88 bytes

```
`Pov:
`»ẆḞẏǒ×Ȯ<§Jṙ¾»»ƛḂ}Ṁ≥⌐$ǍJ₄p∞wj»₁dτCτ6/»⋏∑ṗ»51τ₀*≬⁰L>ḟuJhiøM3`λ• ßµ `꘍?L` on ¬⋎»₅`Wṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgUG92OlxuYMK74bqG4bie4bqPx5LDl8iuPMKnSuG5mcK+wrvCu8ab4biCfeG5gOKJpeKMkCTHjUrigoRw4oied2rCu+KCgWTPhEPPhDYvwrvii4/iiJHhuZfCuzUxz4TigoAq4oms4oGwTD7huJ91Smhpw7hNM2DOu+KAoiDDn8K1IGDqmI0/TGAgb24gwqzii47Cu+KChWBX4bmFIiwiIiwiXCJgUG92OlxcbmDCu+G6huG4nuG6j8eSw5fIrjzCp0rhuZnCvsK7wrvGm+G4gn3huYDiiaXijJAkx41K4oKEcOKInndqwrvigoFkz4RDz4Q2L8K74ouP4oiR4bmXwrs1Mc+E4oKAKuKJrOKBsEw+4bifdUpoacO4TTNgzrvigKIgw5/CtSBg6piNP0xgIG9uIMKs4ouOwrvigoVgV+G5hVwiIl0=)